# PHP CSRF Issue with Form Re submission

Tags: php, post, csrf

I am currently writing my PHP CSRF protection class and it currently works by when a form i sent using POST a token is sent with it, thus I check if the token matches with the token stored in the session and if it does, great....

However, my problem is whenever a HTML form is submitted using POST, if I were to refresh the page using F5 or just refresh the page, it causes the tokens to be out of balance. How can I prevent this form re submission from happening?

My forms need to work by setting the action to the same page, so setting the action in the HTML form to another page/ file is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Reset token after submission and redirect back to form page where you are making form and regenerate token.